# Why FutureBuilder doesn't get call in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a button in my screen and I am calling `_fetchPost()` whenever I click it. This method calls `fetchPost()`. I am able to see my parsed object when I set break point on `var post = ...` line. However, my problem is `builder` won't be called.

I am very new in Flutter, so is my code wrong?

```
void _fetchPost() {
    FutureBuilder<Post>(
      future: fetchPost(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Post> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          String res = snapshot.data.parm1.toString() + snapshot.data.op + snapshot.data.parm2.toString();
          setState(() {
            _result = res;
          });
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          setState(() {
            _result = snapshot.error;
          });
        }

        // By default, show a loading spinner
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }

  Future<Post> fetchPost() async {
    final response = await http.get('http://test.ethorstat.com/test.ashx');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON
      var post = Post.fromJason(json.decode(response.body));
      return post;
    } else {
      // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post!');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Hesam. I am a volunteer editor here, and one of the things that we like to do is to edit questions and answers for succinctness. In particular, niceties such as thanks, appreciations, salutations and signatures are not required in technical writing, and we discourage them. This has been discussed on Meta in this article: [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions)

Comment: @hesam Could you please help me on this same type question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64540805/why-futurebuilder-callback-is-not-calling-after-facebook-logged-in-data-in-flutt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`FutureBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) is a **widget**. This means that in order for it to work, you need to *insert it into the widget tree first*.

Either you add your `FutureBuilder` to the widget tree by returning it as a child to another widget or directly to a `build` function of a widget:

```
class FetchWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => FutureBuilder<Post>(
    future: fetchPost(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Post> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        String res = snapshot.data.parm1.toString() + snapshot.data.op + snapshot.data.parm2.toString();
        setState(() { // setState will not work here, I only used this StatelessWidget to show what I mean with inserting it into the build tree
          _result = res;
        });
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        setState(() {
          _result = snapshot.error;
        });
      }

      // By default, show a loading spinner
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  );

  Future<Post> fetchPost() async {
    final response = await http.get('http://test.ethorstat.com/test.ashx');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON
     var post = Post.fromJason(json.decode(response.body));
     return post;
    } else {
      // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
     throw Exception('Failed to load post!');
    }
  }
}
```

This will not compile because I only copied your code into a `StatelessWidget`, which does not have `setState`. I only wanted to show what I mean by saying *"add [...] to the widget tree"*.

Or you can just use regular `async` `await` for what you are trying to do:

```
void _fetchPost() async {
  final Post fetchedPost = await fetchPost();
  final String res = fetchedPost.parm1.toString() + fetchedPost.op + fetchedPost.parm2.toString();
  setState(() {
    _result = res;
  });
}
```

I am not sure how you want to implement your `fetchPost`, but if you want to use `FutureBuilder`, you need to insert it into the widget tree and return a widget to the `builder`.

Comment: Thanks. So, my underestanding was wrong. I thought I can use `FutureBuilder` just to download something from backend.

Comment: A `FutureBuilder` is a way to process a `Future` in the wiget tree in a neat way. Awaiting a `Future` in a function will do.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Could you please help me on this same type question?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64540805/why-futurebuilder-callback-is-not-calling-after-facebook-logged-in-data-in-flutt